# Firebase Remote Config with Namespace

Tags: android, firebase, namespaces, firebase-remote-config

The Firebase [API for RemoteConfig](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.html#public-methods) has several methods for assigning config values by namespace, eg (`setDefaults(R.xml.rc_defaults, "Namespace")`). I've got this to work in terms of separating config values by namespace on Android, but how to do I set those values by namespace on the Firebase Console for remote updating?

[image: Where is the Namespace assigned?]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I experienced the same problem with you.
So, I asked google Firebase team.

Here's the reply mail.

---

> Hi there,
>   Sorry for the late reply. Currently we don't have any custom namespace feature available. 
>   However, we are aware of the use case and we are actively working on it but I can't share any timelines at the moment.
>
> Keep an eye out on our release notes for any further updates.
>
> Let me know if you have any other questions.
>
> Thanks

---

I hope this answer is little helpful to you :)

Answer (score 3):

I work on Firebase Remote Config team.

As Safa mentioned, Namespaces were only designed for internal usage & are not meant for setting user assigned values. We have begun the process of deprecating the namespace usage from the SDK. Hence I would request not to use them in production code.

We are working on introducing namespaces via another mechanism. Will update this thread once that's ready.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces are intended for introducing future Google services that leverage Remote Config to provide a feature.  They are not meant for setting user assigned values.

Comment: This seems to be in conflict with the statement from the Firebase team as noted by the answer from @WoorazilBoy. Can you verify where you got this information?

Comment: Not quite sure where @WoorazilBoy got his information but I assure you that what I am saying here is correct.  We will make sure that this is reflected in our documentation soon.

Comment: Ok, it sounds as if you are part of the Firebase team(?), but I couldn't verify that. If this gets updated in the documents, let me know and I'll change this to the accepted answer. Until then, @WoorazilBoy's reference seems to be an e-mail from the Firebase team.

Comment: Yes.  I'm part of the team.  We'll get the docs updated soon and I will respond here.

Comment: Hey @SafaAlai, just curious where are we at on this?

Comment: @ScottWood .. see answer by Mayank Jain for update.  (I'm no longer working on Firebase).